# Localizing Identity Error Messages in ASP.NET MVC web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-identity

I already localized the general views of the app e.g., Index.html and some of my other pages. When it was time to localize identity pages (Login, Register e.t.c). it didn't work as expected. I have tried numerous suggestions on here but they didn't seem to work for me

[image]

- Overriding IdentityErrorDescriber
- Creating Resource file in my resource folder - I created the resource file in my resource folder and added ErrorMessages for en and zh and i configured my 'Program.cs' already because like i said, i already localized the general views

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix);

builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new[] { new CultureInfo("en-US"), new CultureInfo("zh-Hans") };
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US");
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRequestLocalization();
```

this all was all to no avail

And in my 'Register.cshtml.cs' I tried to use 'RequiredNum' which i already save in the ErrorMessages resource file as a Key.

```
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "UserName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
```

But instead of getting the value for the key on my page, I got "RequiredNum" on my page like this

[image: Instead of errormessage value, I got the Key]

I would like to ask for help/guidance on how to go about this so that i can successfully localize identity validation error messages. Any help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: `"(Login, Register e.t.c)."`  does these two didn't work or nothing didn't work? Apart from this, other than error message does other localization stuff worked?

Comment: @Md Farid Uddin Kiron other than the error messages on Register.cshtml and Login.cshtml, the localization worked for other pages